# What must I do to have my Interface be at least as accessible as the method in which it is referenced?

Tags: c#, interface, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api, inversion-of-control

I am trying to convert my Controller to use DI.

Based on the [article here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/344078/ASP-NET-WebAPI-Getting-Started-with-MVC4-and-WebAP), I've now got this code:

```
namespace HandheldServer.Controllers
{
    public class DuckbillsController : ApiController
    {
        static IDuckbillRepository _platypiRepository;

        public DuckbillsController(IDuckbillRepository platypiRepository)
        {
            if (platypiRepository == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("platypiRepository is null");
            }
            _platypiRepository = platypiRepository;
        }

        public int GetCountOfDuckbillRecords()
        {
            return _platypiRepository.Get();
        }

        public IEnumerable<Duckbill> GetBatchOfDuckbillsByStartingID(int ID, int CountToFetch)
        {
            return _platypiRepository.Get(ID, CountToFetch);
        }

        public void PostDuckbill(int accountid, string name)
        {
            _platypiRepository.PostDuckbill(accountid, name);
        }

        public HttpResponseMessage Post(Duckbill Duckbill)
        {
            Duckbill = _platypiRepository.Add(Duckbill);
            var response = Request.CreateResponse<Duckbill>(HttpStatusCode.Created, Duckbill);
            string uri = Url.Route(null, new { id = Duckbill.Id });
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri, uri);
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

...but it doesn't compile; I get, "*Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'HandheldServer.Models.IDuckbillRepository' is less accessible than method 'HandheldServer.Controllers.DuckbillsController.DuckbillsController (HandheldServer.Models.IDuckbillRepository)'*"

The interface parameter type mentioned in the err msg is:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace HandheldServer.Models
{
    interface IDuckbillRepository
    {
        int Get();
        IEnumerable<Duckbill> Get(int ID, int CountToFetch);
        Duckbill Add(Duckbill item);
        void Post(Duckbill dept);
        void PostDuckbill(int accountid, string name);
        void Put(Duckbill dept);
        void Delete(int Id);
    }
}
```

What do I need to do to get around this err msg?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explicitly mark the `interface` as `public`:

```
public interface IDuckbillRepository
{
    // ....
}
```

Also, don't mark it `static` in your Controller.

Comment: It is static in the article.

Comment: It shouldn't be. Assuming the repository is set up properly.. it should be re-created on each request.. just as your Controller is. A static property will live for the life of the appdomain.. and if the repository is setup in a "per-request" lifecycle (as it should be).. then you will likely get random errors the more requests you throw at the controller.